# Can the referee give a red card for an incident that happens after the end of a match?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, suspension

In football, if team A wins and a player from team A mocks team B for losing (call them a idiot team, non-fair-play attitude, etc.) can the referee give a red card to that player after the match ends?

Comment: The impact of a red card on a tournament is not something within the LOTG; different competitions assign different penalties for a card (or a set of cards) and even for different reasons for the card(s).

Comment: In the English Premier League, it sometimes happens that players or even coaches are given yellow or red cards for incidents that take place after the final whistle - including in the tunnel when leaving the playing area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, definitely.

Referees can take action as long as they are still on the pitch after the game has ended. This is covered in [Law 5: The Referee](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-referee/)

> [The referee] has the authority to take disciplinary action from
> entering the field of play for the pre-match inspection **until leaving
> the field of play after the match ends** (including kicks from the
> penalty mark). If, before entering the field of play at the start of
> the match, a player commits a sending-off offence, the referee has the
> authority to prevent the player taking part in the match (see Law
> 3.6); the referee will report any other misconduct.